# How to use Hamiltonian Monte Carlo when some parameters result in ill-defined likelihoods?

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, computational-statistics

I want to use Hamiltonian Monte Carlo for an estimation problem where, for some parameters, the solution does not "make sense," so I cannot compute the log likelihood or its gradient. In addition, I do not know a priori what part of the parameter space results in incorrect solutions, so I am unable to restrict the parameter space to use only "good" parameters without doing a brute-force search for the desired restrictions.

Is there a recommended way to deal with this problem? For example, when estimating this model with Random Walk Metropolis Hastings, I would simply set the log likelihood to negative infinity so that the proposal is rejected with probability 1. The proposals will wander around until they reach the region of the parameter space which yields good solutions.

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: The model is a Gaussian linear state space model. The complication arises from the mapping of the parameters $\theta$ to the matrices in the state space model. For example, the state transition equation takes the form
$$ s_t = T(\theta)s_{t-1} + R(\theta) \epsilon_t. $$
Constructing $T(\theta)$ and $R(\theta)$ is not simple; it requires applying a generalized Schur decomposition. However, for some $\theta$, the resulting $T(\theta)$ and $R(\theta)$ are not sensible, and there aren't easy conditions I could check before computing $T(\theta)$ and $R(\theta)$.